# Excel SUMIFS sum_range with variable parameter

Tags: excel, variables, sumifs

So I have an excel spreadsheet indicator and I am trying to make a SUMIFS statement that will change which column I am selecting from. So I will have the column name on the left and I want to use that as a varying parameter. See the below tables.

```
TABLE1
        week1  week2 week3
column1  x       x     x 
column2  x       x     x 
column3  x       x     x

TABLE2
Week column1  column2 column3
  1     x        x       x
  1     x        x       x
  1     x        x       x
  2     x        x       x
  2     x        x       x
  2     x        x       x
```

So in the above tables TABLE2 holds all the data and TABLE1 is basically a sum of the data by week. So I want the SUMIFS to read something like SUMIFS(TABLE2[????], TABLE2[Week], $B$2) But I can't figure out how to get the sum_range part of the SUMIFS to let me pass parameters in. Any tips or ideas on how to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
=INDIRECT("TABLE2[" & A3 & "]")
```

will resolve to TABLE2[column1] (assuming A3 holds the text "column1")

so the indirect function could be put in as your sum_range (tested in excel 2007)

Answer (score 0):

You could use INDEX and MATCH, something like this

`=SUMIFS(INDEX(TABLE2,0,MATCH($A3,$A$7:$D$7,0)),TABLE2[Week],B$2)`

where A3 contains "column1" and A7:D7 contains the column headers for TABLE2

Comment: This is a valid option as a colleague of mine did this, however I was having a lot of issues getting everything lined of and debugged since my actual spreadsheet is a lot more complicated than the example. But thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a SUMPRODUCT formula.  I used Sheet1 and Sheet2 instead of tables.  You may be able to change the formula to suit your needs.
`=SUMPRODUCT(--(Sheet2!$A2 = Sheet1!$B$1:$D$1) * --(Sheet2!B$1 = "week" & Sheet1!$A$2:$A$7), Sheet1!$B$2:$D$7)`